# Rerender table for Apex:repeat is not working

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am trying to reRender table for Apex:repeat on Radio button is not working.In apex controller it is showing exact number of records but on vf page the table is not working.

```
<apex:page id="page" controller="AttachmentListWithFilterController" sidebar="false" readOnly="true">
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jQuery, 'js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js')}"/> 
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jQuery, 'js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js')}"/>
<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jQuery, 'css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css')}"/>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

  <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

 <script type="text/javascript">

             j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
            j$(function () {
            j$("#example1").dataTable();            
        });          

    </script>

    <apex:actionStatus id="actStatusId" >
                <apex:facet name="start" >
                  <img src="/img/loading.gif" />                    
                </apex:facet>
            </apex:actionStatus>

 <!-- <c:waitScreen >
         <img src="/img/loading32.gif" />
         <div style="font-size:150%;padding:5px">Please Wait....</div>
  </c:waitScreen>     -->    

<script type="text/javascript">

        //This will load as soon as the page is ready and will setup our slider
        var str;
        j$ = jQuery.noConflict();

        j$(document).ready(function(){
          var i=0,a=0;

          str = document.getElementById('{!$Component.form.selectedF}').value;

          var b=document.getElementById('{!$Component.page.form.pb.slidervalue.idInputHiddenMax}').value;

          console.log('Value of b'+b);

            $("#slider-range").slider({ //This line creates a slider on the DIV specified, options are passed arguments, comma separated below
                range: true, //This give the slider and top and bottom
                min: 0, //Min value for slider
                max: b, //Max value for slider

                values: ['{!sSliderFieldMin }','{!sSliderFieldMax }'], //Start values for the slider
                slide: function(event, ui){ //This function executes every time slider is moved and applies the slider values to the inputHidden fields as well as the output below the slider
                    document.getElementById('{!$Component.page.form.pb.slidervalue.idInputHiddenMin}').value = ui.values[0];
                    document.getElementById('{!$Component.page.form.pb.slidervalue.idInputHiddenMax}').value = ui.values[1];
                   $("#amountValue").html( + ui.values[0] + 'KB - ' + ui.values[1] + 'KB');

                    //callfind();
                    //console.log(i++);
                },
                stop:function(event,ui){console.log(ui);callfind();}   
            });  

          $("#amountValue").html( + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 0) + 'KB - ' + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 1) + 'KB');
        });

        function checkMethod(){

         var i=0; 
          str = document.getElementById('{!$Component.form.selectedF}').value;
         var b=document.getElementById('{!$Component.page.form.pb.slidervalue.idInputHiddenMax}').value;

          console.log('Value of b'+b);

            $("#slider-range").slider({ //This line creates a slider on the DIV specified, options are passed arguments, comma separated below
                range: true, //This give the slider and top and bottom
                min: 0, //Min value for slider
                max: b, //Max value for slider

                values: ['{!sSliderFieldMin }',b], //Start values for the slider
                slide: function(event, ui){ //This function executes every time slider is moved and applies the slider values to the inputHidden fields as well as the output below the slider
                    document.getElementById('{!$Component.page.form.pb.slidervalue.idInputHiddenMin}').value = ui.values[0];
                    document.getElementById('{!$Component.page.form.pb.slidervalue.idInputHiddenMax}').value = ui.values[1];

                  $("#amountValue").html( + ui.values[0] + 'KB - ' + ui.values[1] + 'KB');


                    //callfind();
                    //console.log(i++);
                },
                stop:function(event,ui){console.log(ui);callfind();}   
            });  

          $("#amountValue").html( + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 0) + 'KB - ' + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 1) + 'KB');
        }
     </script>

         <script type="text/javascript">
           function selectAllCheckboxes(obj,receivedInputID){
                var inputCheckBox = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
                for(var i=0; i<inputCheckBox.length; i++){
                    if(inputCheckBox[i].id.indexOf(receivedInputID)!=-1){
                        inputCheckBox[i].checked = obj.checked;
                    }
                }
            }  
            function selectThis(ele,id){
                if(ele.checked)
                    str+=id;
                else
                    str = str.replace(id,'');
                document.getElementById('{!$Component.form.selectedF}').value = str;
            }


     </script>



 <apex:pageMessages ></apex:pageMessages>

   <apex:Form id="form">
    <apex:inputhidden id="selectedF" value="{!selectedFiles}"/>
       <apex:actionFunction name="callfind" action="{!searchByRange}" reRender="PGTable" status="actStatusId" />
   <apex:pageBlock id="pb" >
   <apex:pageblockSection title="Select Type" collapsible="false">          
             <apex:selectRadio value="{!Selected}">
                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!TakeOther}" reRender="RenderData" onComplete="checkMethod();"/>
                   <apex:selectoptions value="{!radioValues}" />
            </apex:selectRadio>
   </apex:pageBlockSection>
   <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">

        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Select CheckBox</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>BodyLength</th>
                <th>Created Date</th>
                <th>Owner Name</th>
                <th>(Click To View)</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

           <tbody>
           <apex:repeat value="{!wraplist}" id="DemoRepeat" var="a">
           <apex:outputPanel id="RenderData" layout="none">
           <tr>
    <td>  <apex:facet name="header">
                            <apex:inputCheckbox onclick="selectAllCheckboxes(this,'inputId')"/>
                        </apex:facet> 
                        <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!a.selected}" id="inputId" /></td>
    <td> <apex:outputText value="{!a.Name}"/></td>
    <td> <apex:outputText value="{!a.size}"/></td>
    <td> <apex:outputText value="{!a.Mydate}"/></td>
    <td> <apex:outputText value="{!a.OwnerName}"/></td>
    <td>  <apex:commandLink value="View" action="{!viewAttach}" target="_blank" >
                    <apex:param id="Wrapid" name="Attid" value="{!a.index}" assignTo="{!opget}"/>
              </apex:commandLink>&nbsp;
               <apex:commandLink value="Delete" action="{!deleteAttch}" reRender="PGTable">
                      <apex:param id="Deleteid" name="delete" value="{!a.index}" assignTo="{!opget}"/>
                 </apex:commandLink>  </td>
    </tr>
    </apex:outputPanel>


    </apex:repeat>
   </tbody>

    </table>
```

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Have you tried it with `apex:repeat` is inside the `apex:outputPanel`?

Comment: Yes i have tried

Comment: which part do you rerendering. I cannot find where are you using PGTable id.

Comment: I want to reRender Data of apex:repeat so i have implemented one <apex:outputPanel id="RenderData" layout="none"> this part i m going to reRender